# Javascript: Highlighting text based on given indices

Tags: javascript, highlighting

So right now I have functionality where I get a set of indices, and I highlight a text by putting span tags around where those indices fall.

For example, lets I have the following array of indices: [{0,4},{7,11}]

And the text I want to highlight is: "Text I want to highlight"

So basically my function will apply span tags around string where those start and end indices are. Essentially my end product is this:

```
<span class="highlight">Text</span> I <span class="highlight">want</span> to highlight
```

The issue now is that I want to bold (on top of highlight) certain texts. For scenario like above, all is well. But now there can be an overlap between bolding and highlighting. Take the following: [{0,4,highlight},{7,14,highlight},{12,14,bold}]

So the end product would look something like this:

```
   <span class="highlight">Text</span> I <span class="highlight">want </span><span class="highlightandbold>to</span> highlight
```

I've tried a few things, but I want to streamline everything and am having some difficulties. Any help is appreciated.